# MapView Tutorial

Tags: android, google-maps

i followed the exact tutorial on android.com for the mapview, and when i create a HelloItemizedOverlay with just a drawable, it appear but i can't touch it because the onTap() method requiers a context. So i create with a context ( getApplicationContext() ) and it doesn't appear, but if i tap on the place where it needed to be it still crash .
Can someone help me ?

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: Here is complete tutorial of mapview : [Using-google-maps-android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android) hope it helps..

Comment: Follow [Step by step tutorial for Android MapView](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got the context of the overlay, but need the context of the mapview activity, it works for me in this way

```
    public Context mycontext;
public ItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker,Context ctx) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mycontext = ctx;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

Comment: Thanks the thing i didn't do was "boundCenterBottom"., and i put "this" in the main .

Comment: don't forget to boundCenterBottom every drawable you set instead of default (if you do)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to display an `AlarmDialog` like in the tutorial then the context you are getting from `getApplicationContext()` is just not the one you need. You need a `Context` of an `Activity`.

Pass it `this` or `YourActivity.this` (which is the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a same problem two days ago, so in HelloGoogleMaps u write

```
 HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
```

And in itemizedoverlay

```
Context mContext;
    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        super(defaultMarker);
        mContext = context;
    }
```

I think it will work...